# Are there any AirPrint compatible print servers?

Tags: hardware, printing, airprint

We have several printers here at home, and I am thinking about enabling AirPrint. I'm not interested in driver hacks, since they often require a computer to be running with a shared printer.

I am under the impression that there are devices that can be attached to a regular parallel or USB printer which will enable network printing. With this in mind:

Are there any such devices that enable AirPrint? Are there even such wireless devices?

Comment: As a software possibility, I believe PaperCut can make AirPrint available to clients for any CUPS queue it manages. This may be beyond your scope, but if you cannot find hardware solution, perhaps the software can bridge the gap. (Note: this isn't a point'n'click solution). FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one I am aware of is the [Lantronix xPrintServer](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/mobile-print-servers/xprintserver.html).

> xPrintServer fills the gap between the productivity of iPads and iPhones and the inability to print from those devices to office **networked** printers.

<sub>*Bold by me</sub>

Unfortunately it only works for networked printers.

Using a machine as a potential AirPrint server is at this point still the easiest way to enable this.

Answer (score 4):

[Lantronix xPrintServer](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/mobile-print-servers/xprintserver.html) is a hardware device which can be plugged into your network to offer AirPrint services to iOS devices. I haven't used it myself, see [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/01/lantronix-xprintserver-makes-every-network-printer-airprint-ready.ars) for a brief description:

> Simply plug it in to your home or office network, and every printer accessible on your local subnet—be it wired or wireless—will now show as an option when using AirPrint. There's no configuration necessary; any printer that supports JetDirect, LPD, or IPP printing will work, and that includes pretty much every printer with network support.

Comment: Beat me to it. ;)

Comment: The free iPad makes for stiff competition :-)

Comment: All yours my friend—I only commented because my hitting the **Post your Answer** was interrupted by the *new answers posted* notice and our answers were (would have been) nearly identical.

Comment: Who knows why Apple didnt use existing network printer protocols?

Comment: Because nobody wants to spend time tapping away in a window to configure lpd on a goddamned iPad?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but the [Synology NAS](http://www.synology.com/dsm/home_home_applications_print_server.php?lang=us) has this capability to be an AirPrint Print Server

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the $99 "home" xPrintServer does support USB printers - up to 8 with a USB hub (not provided). It also supports 2 network printers, but they've just announced a $199 "office" product that supports unlimited network printers - though they recommend up to 10 for good performance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you go to the Lantronix site to ensure your printer is listed.  It doesn't work with the Canon MF4800 series. But they say it works with the Canon MF9000 series but I think that series already supports AirPrint natively since the MF6000 and MF8000 series do.